# How to add uvicorn code changes to my Python Slack Bolt code?

Tags: python-3.x, uvicorn, slack-bolt

I'm using Slack Bolt Python SDK to create a Slack application in the Socket Mode. My application works and responds to the slash commands given on the app and I can see my method getting invoked as well. I'm trying to achieve automatic reloading of the app when code change happens using `uvicorn` library but I'm unable to get around it.
Following was my original working code before attempting to add uvicorn:-

```
from typing import Optional, Dict, Union, List
from slack_bolt import App
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError
from urllib.parse import unquote
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler
import json

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN']
SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_BOT_TOKEN']
SLACK_APP_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_APP_TOKEN']
app_bolt = App(token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN)


@app_bolt.command("/echo")
def repeat_text(ack, say, command):
    # Acknowledge command request
    ack()
    say(f"{command['text']}")


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     handler = SocketModeHandler(app_bolt, SLACK_APP_TOKEN)
     handler.start()
```

But after adding uvicorn probably in a wrong way, I do not get any hits to my backend code when I typed the slash command on my slash app and I do not see the message like Bold application started in the logs when I my app loads:-

```
INFO:slack_bolt.App:A new session has been established (session id: 28cac339-5cb4-46fd-b8e4-f569ec78f72b)
INFO:slack_bolt.App:⚡️ Bolt app is running!
```

After adding uvicorn:-

```
from uvicorn import run
# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     handler = SocketModeHandler(app_bolt, SLACK_APP_TOKEN)
#     handler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run("main:app_bolt", host="0.0.0.0", port=3000, reload=True, log_level="info")
```

I would really appreciate if someone guide to fix this code so that I can use reloading of code changes during my development using Slack bolt SDK